# Vegas JQuery Background Click

Tags: jquery

Am using the [Vegas Jquery](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) to show images full screen as backgrounds.

Does anyone know a way that I can associate a link to each of these background images? Basically, if they click the background i want to send them off to another page.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an overkill, but have you tried:

```
$.vegas({
  src:'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/images/background-1.jpg',
  fade:2000,
  complete:function() {
      $(this).wrap('<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">');
  }
});
```

like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bldoron/x5dRY/1/)
And I don't promote smoking in any way.

Comment: Tried it, but didnt work for me. Adjustments to the main JS perhaps?

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit? Maybe give us some code? What do you mean by:  "Adjustments to the main JS perhaps?" Did you see my fiddle?

Comment: It works if it is just a background image - but when you overlay content on top of the main body background, the click does not work. Plus I need a different click-through for each background image...

Comment: Do you mean like here: http://jsfiddle.net/bldoron/Md5ev/1/ if so, then wouldn't you expect this behavior? Just write some code to catch the event on the element that was clicked. About different links per image: write a switch/case for each image using an ID, or even the image name. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: Still no go.

my code:

Still no go for some reason. Code I am using -

if(jQuery('.parentitem_1').length)jQuery.vegas('slideshow', {
  delay:10000,
  backgrounds:[
   { src:'/Home1.jpg', fade:2000 },
   { src:'/Home2.jpg', fade:2000 },
   { src:'/Home3.jpg', fade:2000 }
  ]
  complete:function(step) {
  $(this).wrap('<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">');
  }
 });